# send grid email possibly on black list

Tags: email, sendgrid, spam, email-spam

I have been successfully using Sendgrid through Azure to send critical system updates to my clients for some time. All of my emails have suddenly started to become 'Deferred' before either being sent or blocked. I've done some research and there is a chance that my email address has been put onto a Blacklist. All of the emails sent are just, and are in no way spam.

How do I check if I'm on a blacklist and resolve the issue? I know that there are sites out there but I don't want to sign up for any scam services.

Comment: In one of the status message I was able to identify that the blacklist "provider" was SpamHaus.org - I contacted them via email with a reference. They have told me that my service with SendGrid is likely to be using a shared IP address and that IP address is also being used for malicious activity; that they cannot help but that I need to contact SendGrid... (waiting for SendGrid to resolve support ticket)

Comment: Same issue, and I've been waiting four weeks for support to return my emails. This is an issue with SendGrid at large, more info can be seen here: https://krebsonsecurity.com/2020/08/sendgrid-under-siege-from-hacked-accounts/

Answer (score 6):

No response from SendGrid support so I updated to the 'Silver' offer which supplies me with a dedicated IP address (and fixed the problem). I believe that the problem came from the fact that I was using a shared IP (supplied by SendGrid) as part of the lower package.